# Socket Messaging Client/Server: Client not sending message

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a simple chat program using Python and Socket. The server handles the connection between two clients. Whenever I run the program, for one of the clients, every message after the first one does not send. The message does not even reach the server.

This is on Windows, Python3. I've integrated threading so messages can be sent and received at the same time; however, the problem persists.

Server.py

```
conns = [] # list that stores both connections


def accept(sk):
    while True:
        conn, addr = sk.accept()
        conns.append(conn)
        print(addr, "has connected")

    t = threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(sk,))
    t.start() #start accept thread



def send(conn):
    while True:
        message = conn.recv(2048)
        print(message)
        for conn in conns:
            conn.send(message) #sends message to every connection
            print("Sent message")


t = threading.Thread(target=send, args=(conn,))
t.start() #start threading for send
```

Client.py

```
def recvMessages(s):
    while True:
        message = s.recv(2048)
        print(message)
        message = message.decode()
        messages.append(message)
        os.system("cls")

        for message in messages:
            print(message)

def sendMessage(s):
    while True:
        message = input()
        message = message.encode()
        s.send(message)

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))
messages = []

print("Connected")
connected = True




threading.Thread(target=sendMessage, args=(s,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=recvMessages, args=(s,)).start()
```

All the messages should be sent from both clients, but one client can never send multiple messages, the other works fine.

Comment: Receiving messages in a method called `send()`, and *vice versa,* is poor practice, but your server sends every incoming message to every client, including the sender, which is probably bottling up the system.

Comment: @user207421: How would I implement this then? What would be better practice?

Comment: Because of the messed up formatting of your code I can make no sense of it. Please check and correct the indentation.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I apologize.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense because it appears that the thread that runs accept is in the body of accept. I'll assume it should not be indented that way.

Comment: First of all, in the server your use of `conns` is unsafe due to the potential for unsynchronized concurrent modification. That is likely to cause only intermittent breakage, however. Also, it's unclear where the `conn` argument to `send` is coming from.

Comment: How you should fix it is by not sending messages back to their origin, and by fixing your code so that methods called `send()` don't also do receives, and *vice versa.* This all seems rather obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server code is missing it's socket, and accept is not being run in your example, you also have invalid indentation as James pointed out, next time provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I also cleaned up your files a bit, as you followed some bad practice, specifically with broadcasting the messages to all clients "def send" which actually receives, avoid confusing naming :)

in your server code you also sent only to one connection (which in your example doesn't exist) which it should be running the receive and send each time a new message is received

**server.py**

```
import socket
import threading

conns = []  # list that stores both connections


def accept(sk):
    while True:
        conn, addr = sk.accept()
        conns.append(conn)
        print(addr, "has connected")

        # receive from new client
        receive_t = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=(conn,))

        receive_t.start()  # start threading for send


def send(s, msg):

        # change message ..
        s.send(msg)  


def broadcast(msg):
    for conn in conns:
        send(conn, msg)


def receive(conn):
    try:
        while True:
            message = conn.recv(2048)

            if not message: # detects if socket is dead, by testing message
                print("client sent Nothing, removing") 
                conns.remove(conn)
                break
            broadcast(message)  # send to all clients
    except ConnectionResetError  as e:
        print('Could not send must be disconnected ')
        conns.remove(conn) # remove dead socket



# added missing socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
sock.listen(1)  # needs to  bind and listen
t = threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(sock,))
t.start()  # start accept thread
```

**client.py**

```
import os
import socket
import threading

messages = []


def recvMessages(s):
    while True:
        message = s.recv(2048)

        message = message.decode()
        print('new message= ', message)
        messages.append(message)
        os.system("cls")

        for message in messages:
            print(message)


def send_message(s):
    while True:
        message = input()
        message = message.encode()
        s.send(message)


s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))

print("Connected")
connected = True
# added missing receive

receive = threading.Thread(target=recvMessages, args=(s,)) # missed receive thread in example
receive.start()
send_message(s)
```